# How to make a sub menu from a parent menu

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n3tzbn4o/2/

Sample Css:

```
/* Reset */
.menu, .menu2,
.menu ul, .menu2 ul,
.menu li, .menu2 li,
.menu a, .menu2 a,
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

For the parent menu `menu 3` sub menu `2015`, how come the sub submenu is inheriting from the `menu` class and not the `menu2` class? Also, how come the hover doesn't change color for the second item inside the `menu2` class `ul`.

Please help me resolve the issue

Comment: I suggest you read about [Specificity and Inheritance](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/css-specificity-and-inheritance/) in CSS. All the rules that match apply on an element. They just have different importance, based on selectors specificity and order of CSS rules (from a set of equal strength selectors the last one read applies). Between `.parent .child` and `.grand-parent .child` the one with the closer parent applies (so first one).

Comment: Side note: these css only menus can quite hard to use due to the diagonal problem. See for instance [Breaking down Amazon’s mega dropdown](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the parent menu `menu 3` sub menu `2015`, how come the sub submenu is inheriting from the `menu` class and not the `menu2` class?

Actually, the sub submenu is inheriting from the `.menu2` class.

[image]

> Also, how come the hover doesn't change color for the second item inside the `menu2` class `ul.

Because you have a syntax error in your `li` tags.

[image]

Correct the tags from `<l1> ... </l1>` to `<li> ... </li>`, and the link will work.